# Javadoc tag for performance considerations

Tags: java, documentation, comments, javadoc

Is there a javadoc tag for performance considerations?

One could imagine:

```
/**
 * ...other javadoc tags...
 * @perform Expected to run in O(n) time if image exists with O(k) memory usage
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
     //code goes here
```

If it is not built in, is there some de facto custom tag that people use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a standard, really. If you were to do this, just maintain a format you (or your org) prefers and keep consistent.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 8, a new tag has been added for this kind of consideration called `@implNote`.

As described [here](http://blog.codefx.org/java/new-javadoc-tags/) it can be used like this:

```
/**
 * Picks the winners from the specified set of players.
 * <p>
 * The returned list defines the order of the winners, where the first
 * prize goes to the player at position 0. The list will not be null but
 * can be empty.
 * @implNote This implementation has linear runtime and does not filter out
 *           null players.
 * @param players
 *            the players from which the winners will be selected
 * @return the (ordered) list of the players who won; the list will not
 *         contain duplicates
 * @since 1.1
 */
default List<String> pickWinners(Set<String> players) {
    return new ArrayList<>(players);
}
```

There are also two other tags added which are discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619575/1456253) question.

It is worth noting that there is some detail about these not being part of the javadoc spec, and instead being something used by oracle and extensively in the JDK. Because of this, the same source as above details that you have to use the following command line options to enable them:

```
-tag "apiNote:a:API Note:"
-tag "implSpec:a:Implementation Requirements:"
-tag "implNote:a:Implementation Note:"
```

They have differing amount of support across IDEs (for instance you cannot set the above command line arguments in Eclipse), which makes them less useful than they could be.